# In DB2, can a CTE be used in the table-expression of a Merge or Update statement..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

In DB2-400 v7r3m0, can a common table expression (CTE) be used in the table-expression of a Merge or Update statement..?

There is [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864343/can-a-db2-with-statement-be-used-as-part-of-an-update-or-merge), which on the surface is an exact duplicate of my question. However, the article is 8 years old, and none of the OP, answers, or comments indicate the versions of DB2. Across the many years, platforms, and versions of DB2 there may have been changes or improvements that now allow what I wish to do.

Below is an SQL script which results in three result tables. There are temp tables, table expressions, and CTEs. The whole thing works, except for the commented part with `CTE3`, which displays the following error:

`SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword AS not expected. Valid tokens: FULL LEFT CROSS INNER RIGHT EXCEPTION.`

I also tried this with an Update statement, and received a similar error indicating different keywords were expected.

The commented SECTION is a near-exact copy of the statement above it, with the only change being the CTE. Can thE commented SECTION be made to work..?

```
-- CREATE HYPOTHETICAL TABLE. USE A CTE.
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TESTTABLE
    AS  (   WITH CTE1 AS (  SELECT      *
                            FROM        TABLE(VALUES(1,'BE'),(2,'BI'),(3,'BN')
                                             ) AS TMP (ID,PCLASS)
                         )
            SELECT  *
            FROM    CTE1
        )   WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ;

-- CREATE TABLE WITH CHANGES TO PUT IN PREVIOUS TABLE.
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.NEWVALUES
    AS  (   SELECT      *
            FROM        TABLE(VALUES(1,'XX'),(2,'YY'),(3,'ZZ')
                        ) AS TMP (ID,QCLASS)
        )   WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ;

-- SHOW THE FIRST TABLE.
SELECT      *
FROM        SESSION.TESTTABLE ;

-- MAKE A SIMPLE WORKING CTE, AND USE IT TO SHOW THE 2ND TABLE.
WITH        CTE2 AS (   SELECT  ID, QCLASS 
                        FROM    SESSION.NEWVALUES
                    )
SELECT      * 
FROM        CTE2 ;

-- THE FOLLOWING WORKS. IT MERGES CHANGES FROM 2ND TABLE INTO THE 1ST.
MERGE INTO      SESSION.TESTTABLE AS TT
USING           (   SELECT  ID, QCLASS 
                    FROM    SESSION.NEWVALUES
                )   AS NV   ON TT.ID = NV.ID
--WHEN MATCHED    THEN              -- UPDATE ALL RECORDS
WHEN MATCHED    AND TT.ID=2 THEN    -- UPDATE ONLY RECORD #2
                    UPDATE SET TT.PCLASS = NV.QCLASS ;

-- THIS FOLLOWING DOESN'T WORK AND DISPLAYS THIS ERROR:
--      SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword AS not expected. 
--      Valid tokens: FULL LEFT CROSS INNER RIGHT EXCEPTION.
/*
MERGE INTO      SESSION.TESTTABLE AS TT
USING           (   WITH CTE3 AS (   SELECT  ID, QCLASS 
                                     FROM    SESSION.NEWVALUES
                                 )
                    SELECT  * 
                    FROM    CTE3     -- CTE USED HERE
                )   AS NV   ON TT.ID = NV.ID
--WHEN MATCHED    THEN              -- UPDATE ALL RECORDS
WHEN MATCHED    AND TT.ID=2 THEN    -- UPDATE ONLY RECORD #2
                    UPDATE SET TT.PCLASS = NV.QCLASS ;
*/

-- SHOW THE FIRST TABLE AGAIN, BUT NOW WITH THE CHANGES.
SELECT      *
FROM        SESSION.TESTTABLE ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a DB2 WITH statement be used as part of an UPDATE or MERGE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864343/can-a-db2-with-statement-be-used-as-part-of-an-update-or-merge)

Comment: I've edited the OP to indicate the linked article is 8 years old. There have been many changes and improvements to DB2 since then, and what I wish to do may now be possible.

Comment: Fair enough.  Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge, the answer is still the same...  I have not had a chance to look through the documentation for 7.4 or play with that yet however I haven't seen anything in the IBM i articles I perused about it either.

Comment: Thank you. Despite the age of the article, I'm pretty sure the idea of unflattening the chain of CTEs into a rats nest of subselects is still a perfectly valid way of increasing convolution and decreasing readability. I was just trying to avoid it. =-)

Comment: You're not wrong!  Just because something is the best way available of accomplishing a goal does not make it a GOOD way :)

Answer (score 2):

The `WITH` common table expression (CTE) for Db2 for i 7.4 is documented here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzintsel.htm

it shows that you can use a *full-select* after the CTE.

UPDATE is documented here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzupdt.htm

but does not show that `UPDATE` can use a CTE, although it does say you can update a (updatable) VIEW, and views support CTEs https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzhcview.htm

Similar is the case for `MERGE`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzmerge.htm

Comment: Thank you for the links. I did refer to those pages for `UPDATE` and `MERGE` (for 7.3 as mentioned in my OP), and alone I wouldn't have discerned the details which you've pointed out. But now I see them plainly. I'll consider other options, such as a nested subselect  or updateable view, probably the latter.